Extract the effective degrees of freedom (EDF) from a Generalized Additive Model (GAM) applied to an imputed dataset
How do you extract the pooled estimated degrees of freedom (edf)  from a pooled generalized additive model ?
library(mice)  # For multiple imputation
library(mgcv)  # For GAM models
library(broom) # For tidying model outputs

# Create a Sample Dataset
set.seed(123)  # for reproducibility
n <- 100
df <- data.frame(
  outcome_score = rnorm(n, 100, 15),
  exposure = rnorm(n, 0.5, 0.1)
)
df$exposure[sample(1:n, 20)] <- NA
imp <- mice(df, m = 5, method = 'pmm', seed = 500)

# Fit GAMs on MICEed data
micegam <- with(imp,  gam(outcome_score ~ s(exposure, bs = "bs")))

I tried the following:
poolgam <- pool(micegam)
summary_poolgam <- summary(poolgam)
tidy_poolgam <- tidy(poolgam, conf.int = TRUE)


You could bind the imputed datasets in a long format and calculate EDF by each imputation.
> cpl <- complete(imp, action='long')
> Edf <- by(cpl, ~.imp, \(X) {
+   edf <- gam(outcome_score ~ s(exposure, bs = "bs"), data=X)$edf
+   c(edf['(Intercept)'], total=sum(edf))
+ }) |> do.call(what='rbind')
> Edf
  (Intercept)    total
1           1 2.500043
2           1 2.000000
3           1 2.856669
4           1 2.565222
5           1 2.000000

The pooled EDF should be the colMeans I guess, as pooled estimates usually are the mean of the estimates of each imputation.
> colMeans(Edf)
(Intercept)       total 
   1.000000    2.384387 

